# rsync --include multiple directories only syncing top level

Tags: rsync

I'm trying to rsync three directories and all their contents from a remote server to a local folder, using the following command:

```
rsync -havzP --delete --include 'content/***' --include 'data/***' --include 'public/assets/***' --exclude '*'  user@host:path/ ./
```

The intention being that the tree structure would be maintained, so I'd end up with this locally:

```
* content
  * [files]
* data
  * [files]
* public
  * assets
    * [files]
```

It mostly works perfectly, except it only syncs content and data, public/assets is not downloading for some reason.

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out thanks to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46227148/39428

`public/assets/***` wasn't being included because the exclude rule was excluding `public`. So that has to be included as well:

```
rsync -havzP --delete --include 'content/***' --include 'data/***' --include='public' --include 'public/assets/***' --exclude '*'  user@host:path/ ./
```